# Highlight selected listview item with highlighter effect

Tags: android, listview, android-cursoradapter

I have a listview, and it is multiple select. Everytime i select an item, it must be highlighted.. however i want it to be a highlighter effect instead of coloring the whole row

Goal:
[image]

Instead of this:
[image]

Main Activity Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.peace.webelieve.Niv">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/seekBar2" 
    android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"/>

<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/listView2"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/listView2" />
```

Custom list layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/item_version"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
    android:typeface="serif"
android:background="@drawable/list_row"

    android:paddingStart="20dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to create a custom row for you `ListView` (your row will contains `TextView` and ...).
Then you should set the background for your custom row, it will prevent your row hightlight when you pressed.
Finally, you add the selector for the background of your `TextView`, when textview state is pressed -> change textview background

For your listview

```
  <ListView
   ...
   android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" // add this line for disable ListView hightlight when press
  />
```

Your custom row layout

```
<LinerLayout
  android:layout_width = "match_parent"
  android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
  android:background = "#f00" // set background for your custom cell for preventing row change color when it selected>

  <TextView
   android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
   android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
   android:background = "@drawable/textview_selection" // add selector for the background of your textview />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then you create a `textview_selection` layout in your drawable folder

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/selected_background" />
 </selector>
```

And also create xml file `selected_background`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 android:shape="rectangle">
 <solid android:color="#0000ff" />
</shape>
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thank you so much for your response :) but the whole row is still highlighted, my goal is only the text is highlighted like the first image, is this possible?

Comment: @PeacegleMayor I have updated my answer, I have add one more line in the `ListView`. Could you check it again then tell me the result

Comment: it's still like the second image above

Comment: add your layout in your question then i will easy for check

Comment: please add your `ListView` row layout code to your question

Comment: i added the my custom layout for listview